# Why do I have to chain Stream operations in Java?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I think all of the resources I have studied one way or another emphasize that a stream can be consumed only once, and the consumption is done by so-called terminal operations (which is very clear to me).

Just out of curiosity I tried this:

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntStream is = IntStream.of(1, 2, 3, 4);
        is.map(i -> i + 1);
        int sum = is.sum();
    }
}
```

which ends up throwing a Runtime Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:229)
    at java.util.stream.IntPipeline.reduce(IntPipeline.java:456)
    at java.util.stream.IntPipeline.sum(IntPipeline.java:414)
    at App.main(scratch.java:10)
```

This is usual, I am missing something, but still want to ask: As far as I know `map` is an intermediate (and lazy) operation and does *nothing* on the Stream by itself. Only when the terminal operation `sum` (which is an eager operation) is called, the Stream gets *consumed* and *operated on*.

But why do I have to chain them?

What is the difference between

```
is.map(i -> i + 1);
is.sum();
```

and

```
is.map(i -> i + 1).sum();
```

?

Comment: *A stream should be operated on (invoking an intermediate or terminal stream operation) only once. This rules out, for example, "forked" streams, where the same source feeds two or more pipelines, or multiple traversals of the same stream. A stream implementation may throw IllegalStateException if it detects that the stream is being reused. However, since some stream operations may return their receiver rather than a new stream object, it may not be possible to detect reuse in all cases.*

Comment: all streams are driven by a spliterator, and each spliterator is only useful for a single bulk computation

Answer (score 46, accepted):

When you do this:

```
int sum = IntStream.of(1, 2, 3, 4).map(i -> i + 1).sum();
```

Every chained method is being invoked *on the return value* of the previous method in the chain.

So `map` is invoked on what `IntStream.of(1, 2, 3, 4)` returns and `sum` on what `map(i -> i + 1)` returns.

You don't have to chain stream methods, but it's more readable and less error-prone than using this equivalent code:

```
IntStream is = IntStream.of(1, 2, 3, 4);
is = is.map(i -> i + 1);
int sum = is.sum();
```

Which is not the same as the code you've shown in your question:

```
IntStream is = IntStream.of(1, 2, 3, 4);
is.map(i -> i + 1);
int sum = is.sum();
```

As you see, you're disregarding the reference returned by `map`. This is the cause of the error.

---

**EDIT** (as per the comments, thanks to @IanKemp for pointing this out): Actually, this is the *external* cause of the error. If you stop to think about it, `map` must be doing something *internally* to the stream itself, otherwise, how would then the terminal operation trigger the transformation passed to `map` on each element? I agree in that intermediate operations are lazy, i.e. when invoked, they do nothing to the elements of the stream. But internally, they must configure some state into the stream pipeline itself, so that they can be applied later.

Despite I'm not aware of the full details, what happens is that, conceptually, `map` is doing at least 2 things:

1. It's creating and returning a new stream that holds the function passed as an argument somewhere, so that it can be applied to elements later, when the terminal operation is invoked.
2. It is also setting a flag to the old stream instance, i.e. the one which it has been called on, indicating that this stream instance no longer represents a valid state for the pipeline. This is because the new, updated state which holds the function passed to `map` is now encapsulated by the instance it has returned. (I believe that this decision might have been taken by the jdk team to make errors appear as early as possible, i.e. by throwing an early exception instead of letting the pipeline go on with an invalid/old state that doesn't hold the function to be applied, thus letting the terminal operation return unexpected results).

Later on, when a terminal operation is invoked on this instance flagged as invalid, you're getting that `IllegalStateException`. The two items above configure the deep, internal cause of the error.

---

Another way to see all this is to make sure that a `Stream` instance is operated only once, by means of either an intermediate or a terminal operation. Here you are violating this requirement, because you are calling `map` and `sum` on the same instance.

In fact, [javadocs for `Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) state it clearly:

> A stream should be operated on (invoking an intermediate or terminal stream operation) only once. This rules out, for example, "forked" streams, where the same source feeds two or more pipelines, or multiple traversals of the same stream. A stream implementation may throw `IllegalStateException` if it detects that the stream is being reused. However, since some stream operations may return their receiver rather than a new stream object, it may not be possible to detect reuse in all cases.

Comment: @Koray To add to that, adding a debug point at both your lines `is.map(i -> i + 1);
int sum = is.sum();`, you can notice the change in the IntPipeline `is` which is what you are not reusing and I believe since `is` is already marked as `linkedOrConsumed` in your case, you see an ISE.

Comment: Is it safe to term it as the *intermediate operation memorization* was the step that the asker has missed?

Comment: @nullpointer I'm not sure. *Memorization* sounds too similar to *memoization*, which is a completely different thing... Maybe *tracking* is a better term?

Comment: This feels very similar to the age old `str.toLowerCase();` vs `s = str.toLowerCase();` stumbling block in Java

Comment: "As you see, you're disregarding the reference returned by map. This is the cause of the error." - that doesn't make sense to me. As the asker has noted, `map()` is an intermediate operation, which means that applying it and then throwing away the result via `is.map(i -> i + 1);` *should have no effect on the underlying stream*, and thus calling the terminal operation `int sum = is.sum();` on that underlying stream should still succeed.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner See, this is the kind of in-depth technical explanation I would hope to see in an answer on Stack Overflow (hint hint). But I'm still confused by one thing, namely the fact that the call to the intermediate op sets an "invalid" flag on the original stream: surely this flag should only be raised when a terminal op is invoked?

Comment: I agree with @IanKemp that this answer doesn't really answer the question. As the intermediate operations return a new stream, one would think that the old stream stays untouched. The interface suggests immutability.

Comment: I've always understood "chaining" to be when each method returns `this`. That's obviously not what's happening here, at least functionally. Is it still chaining?

Comment: @TheWanderer Chaining refers to method calls, not to instances, i.e. `list.get(0).toString().substring(3)` is a chain of methods.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 15):

Imagine the IntStream is a wrapper around your data stream with an 
immutable list of operations. These operations are not executed until you need the final result (sum in your case). 
Since the list is immutable, you need a new instance of IntStream with a list that contains the previous items plus the new one, which is what '. map' returns.

This means that if you don't chain, you will operate on the old instance, which does not have that operation.

The stream library also keeps some internal tracking of what's going on, that's why it's able to throw the exception in the `sum` step.

If you don't want to chain, you can use a variable for each step:

```
IntStream is = IntStream.of(1, 2, 3, 4);
IntStream is2 = is.map(i -> i + 1);
int sum = is2.sum();
```

Answer (score 3):

> Intermediate operations return a new stream. They are always lazy; executing an intermediate operation such as filter() does not actually perform any filtering, but instead creates a new stream that, when traversed, contains the elements of the initial stream that match the given predicate.

Taken from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html under "Stream Operations and Pipelines"

> At the lowest level, all streams are driven by a spliterator.

Taken from the same link under "Low-level stream construction"

> Traversal and splitting exhaust elements; each Spliterator is useful for only a single bulk computation.

Taken from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html

Comment: Yes ... but that doesn't explain what happens if you ignore the result.

Comment: you were right, i updated my answer